# Como alterar a pasta "build" padrão de projeto flutter?

Tags: flutter

Tenho um projeto flutter, porém sempre uso 2 máquinas para trabalhar, o código-fonte fica no Google Drive.

Problema: a pasta "build", ".idea", ".dart_tool" ficam sempre fazendo upload no Drive, desnecessariamente, visto que são gerados nelas arquivos temporários.

Como tirar essas pasta da estrutura do projeto..

Criar um caminho como C:\flutter\projetox\build para nessa pasta gerar os arquivos?

Tentei com link simbólico, mas também não funciona, porque o Drive sobe do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Você já considerou utilizar o github? https://docs.github.com/pt/get-started/getting-started-with-git

Comment: Vou dá uma estudada, mas não sei se resolveria meu caso.. a questão é que não queria ficar subindo arquivos desnecessários... como isso poderia ser resolvido com o github?

Comment: O git é um repositório especifico para guardarmos nossos projetos, não sei se você já é da área mas é bom conhecer pq 99% das empresas utilizam. No caso de não querer subir um arquivo especifico ou pasta ele tem um arquivo chamado "gitignore" onde vc especifica quais arquivos ou pastas ele deve ignorar https://docs.github.com/pt/get-started/getting-started-with-git/ignoring-files

Answer (score 0):

Para evitar que as pastas "build", ".idea" e ".dart_tool" sejam sincronizadas pelo Google Drive, você pode adicioná-las ao arquivo ".gitignore" do seu projeto.

O arquivo ".gitignore" é usado pelo Git (um sistema de controle de versão) para determinar quais arquivos e pastas devem ser ignorados quando você faz um commit (salva as alterações) no repositório. Qualquer arquivo ou pasta adicionada ao arquivo ".gitignore" não será incluído nos commits e, portanto, não será sincronizado pelo Google Drive.

Para adicionar as pastas "build", ".idea" e ".dart_tool" ao arquivo ".gitignore", basta adicionar as seguintes linhas ao arquivo:

build/
.idea/
.dart_tool/

Depois de adicionar essas linhas ao arquivo ".gitignore", você precisará fazer um commit para que as alterações sejam salvas no repositório. Isso fará com que essas pastas sejam ignoradas pelo Git e, portanto, não sejam sincronizadas pelo Google Drive.

É importante notar que essa abordagem só funcionará se você estiver usando o Git para controlar o código-fonte do seu projeto. Se você não estiver usando o Git, outra opção é mover essas pastas para fora do diretório do projeto e, em seguida, criar links simbólicos para elas no diretório do projeto. Isso fará com que elas apareçam no diretório do projeto, mas não serão incluídas no Google Drive.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica, já estou fazendo a criação de link simbólico, mas não, fica algo muito elegante, e tem o aquivos direto, como o pubspec.yaml

Eu não uso o Git, estava procurando uma forma mais "nativa" de resolver isso no Google Drive... algum arquivo que pudesse colocar para ele mesmo ignorar tal pasta.

Ou então algo para resolver na configuração do flutter, para ele gerar estes arquivo fora do diretório dos demais.. seria uma configuração simples, para informar o caminho do "build" e outros arquivos.